# Как присвоить переменной значение из label другого диалогового окна?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Есть два диалоговых окна в первом есть label в котором содержится некоторое значение его мне нужно поместить в переменную во втором диалоговом окне в qt creator. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможно, что я уже сплю и поэтому испытываю легкое недоумение, но Вы уверены, что понятно сформулировали свою проблему и что у Вас вообще есть проблема с "копи/пасте"? На всякий случай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Да, вроде правильно сформулировал, есть два диалоговых окна в первом есть label в котором содержится некоторое значение его мне нужно поместить в переменную во втором диалоговом окне, я не знаю как это сделать, так надеюсь понятнее

Comment: используйте механизм сигналов и слотов.

Answer (score 1):

Общепринятым способом является создание класса, который наследует от QDialog и получает нужные данные в параметры конструктора. Далее он открывается модально (исполнение метода блокируется до закрытия диалога), используя QDialog::exec(), и после закрытия полученные данные вытягиваются [геттерами](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFIxFMNNejA).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**dialog.h**

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QLineEdit *edit;
    QPushButton *button;

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0, QString text = "");
    ~Dialog();

public slots:
    void ButtonClick();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent, QString text) : QDialog(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "constructor: " << text;

    edit = new QLineEdit(this);
    edit->setText(text);
    edit->move(10,10);

    button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setText("Open dialog");
    button->move(10,50);

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Dialog::ButtonClick);
}

void Dialog::ButtonClick()
{
    Dialog dialog(this, edit->text());
    qDebug() << "before show";
    dialog.exec();
    qDebug() << "after show";
}

Dialog::~Dialog(){ }
```

Понаблюдай за текстом, который выводится в Application Output. Если будут вопросы, я отвечу на них в комментариях.